# Powershell Profile to append parameters to a certain command

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-cli

I have a certain command that I want to be able to append a parameter to as a powershell profile function. Though I'm not quite sure the best way to be able to capture each time this command is run, any insight would be helpful.

Command: `terraform plan`

Each time a plan is run I want to be able to check the parameters and see if `-lock=true` is passed in and if not then append `-lock=false` to it. Is there a suitable way to capture when this command is run, without just creating a whole new function that builds that command? So far the only way I've seen to capture commands is with `Start-Transcript` but that doesn't quite get me to where I need.

Comment: Can you attempt this yourself and post the results? I can help with this, but would like to see you give it a shot first:)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I haven't given it a true attempt yet as I am not sure where to start unless I created something like 
```function tf-plan {
    // run terraform plan with necessary arguments
}```
but that's not the intended action trying to do, so I'm doing a ton of research to see if theres something to do to capture input commands before they are run

Comment: The ideal implementation would be more like an event driven powershell function that says "hey this command is about to be executed, but I'm capturing it prior to being run and editing it" that way terraform cli can still be used as intended, and this is more of an extension to it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you tab-complete the parameters for `terraform`?

Comment: no you cannot, just tried `terraform pl` and hit tab, nothin.

Comment: can you show me how you would run the command? I.e.: `terraform plan blah blah -lock=true`, or `terraform plan blah blah`? Then append `-lock=false` like `terraform plan blah blah -lock=false` if not present? @NattyMojo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to create a wrapper function that analyzes its arguments and adds `-lock=false` as needed before calling the `terraform` utility.

```bash
function terraform {
  $passThruArgs = $args
  if (-not ($passThruArgs -match '^-lock=')) { $passThruArgs += '-lock=false'}
  & (Get-Command -Type Application terraform) $passThruArgs
}
```

The above uses the same name as the utility, effectively shadowing the latter, as is your intent.

However, I would caution against using the same name for the wrapper function, as it can make it hard to understand what's going on.

Also, if defined globally via `$PROFILE` or interactively, any unsuspecting code run in the same session will call the wrapper function, unless an explicit path or the shown `Get-Command` technique is used.

Comment: I think this is going to end up working for me, tweaked slightly for some use cases, but otherwise great, and works with aliases. Thanks for helping me along @mklement0

Answer (score 3):

Not to take away from the other answer posted, but to offer an alternative solution here's my take:

```bash
$Global:CMDLETCounter = 0
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.PreCommandLookupAction = {
    Param($CommandName, $CommandLookupEvents)
    if ($CommandName -eq 'terraform' -and $Global:CMDLETCounter -eq 0)
    {
        $Global:CMDLETCounter++
        $CommandLookupEvents.CommandScriptBlock = {
            if ($Global:CMDLETCounter -eq 1) 
            { 
                if (-not ($args -match ($newArg = '-lock=')))
                {
                    $args += "${newArg}true"
                }
            }
            & "terraform" @args
            $Global:CMDLETCounter--
        }
    }
}
```

You can make use of the [`$ExecutionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#executioncontext) *automatic variable* to tap into PowerShells parser and insert your own logic for a specific expression. In your case, youd be using `terraform` which the command input will be parsed for each token and checked against `-lock=` in the existing arguments. If not found, append `-lock=true` to the current arguments and execute the command again.

The counter you see (`$Global:CMDLETCounter`) is to prevent an endless loop as it would just recursively call itself without there being something to halt it.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the answer, though as I've aliased the actual terraform command, and that is also something that I have to take into consideration, this won't work for me. Great answer though, certainly is closer to what I was going for.

Comment: No problem. You can also include the alias in here as well.